# Decode this... before it's too late

Tags: cipher

Note: Story does not contain any clues

> You are a detective trying to find out the whereabouts of a very dangerous criminal. You have captured his accomplice, who refuses to give you any information. Luckily, you have found three different notes from the criminal that the accomplice had with him.

First note:

> First
>
> Express yourself
>
> Tell your friends and family how much they mean to you,
>
> Tell them...before it's too late.
>
> Under the ground, a being stirs
>
> Bringer of death, he strikes
>
> Reaps your soul
>
> Under the ground you go
>
> Terror strikes
>
> End.

Second Note:

> Second
>
> All life must die
>
> Ukuleles play the song of life
>
> Am I alive or dead?
>
> Funny how I don't know
>
> By Arizona
>
> Apache people live
>
> Apache understand life and death like no other

Third note:

> wba
>
> hvsp
>
> rshsh
>
> qhwt
>
> jsgg
>
> ohhh
>
> wqz

**Hint #1:**

> Each note gives clues about how to solve the next one

After about 18 hours if this is not solved I will give another hint.

Partial (correct) answers will earn an upvote, person who contributed the most to the solution (or solved by themselves) will get accepted answer. Good luck.

Comment: I would not worry about too much of my puzzle not being solved in 18 hours.

Comment: Please read [this about giving hints](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5005/when-should-i-add-hints-to-my-puzzle).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Answer:**

> In your own attic.

Note 1:

> The word "first" tells us to take the first letter of each sentence. These say `ETTUBRUTE` which indicates a Caesar cipher. (Thanks to @Rubio for solving this part.)

Note 2:

> The second letter of each sentence is `lkmuypp` which with a Caesar shift of 16 becomes `backoff`.

Note 3:

> Dropping the last letter of each line (taking the "back off") gives `wbhvsrshsqhwjsgohhwq` which rot-12s to `inthedetectivesattic`.

Comment: Nice job, you got it!

Answer (score 3):

**Partial Answer**
Note 1:

> reading down the first letters (excluding the "First" line) gives
>  **ETTBRUTE**
>  which seems sufficiently similar to Et tu, Brute - the line attributed to Caesar - to not be a coincidence.  Is there a "U" line missing?
>
>  In any case, this hints at a Caesar cipher for Note 2.  While I'm not able to find anything in Note 2 that caesars to anything useful, I thought I'd toss this out there and see if it stirs anyone else's thinking.

Comment: Yes, you figured out the first note, I fixed the typo also.